# List<Button> as properties. Not adding buttons to panel

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to create a custom panel where I can change the properties using Properties -> Buttons -> [(Collection) ...]:

The following is what I have tried

```
public class CustomPanel : Panel
{
    private List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>();

    public List<Button> Buttons
    {
        get { return buttons; }
        set 
        {
             buttons = value;
             this.Controls.Clear();
                
             foreach (var button in buttons)
             {
                button.Size = new Size(200, 30);
                this.Controls.Add(button);
             }
         }
    }
}
```

But when I add a new button using Properties -> Buttons -> [(Collection) ...]: it is not adding it to my panel.

Comment: You should set the Location in some way, too!

Comment: Note that the setter of the property will only be triggered when you assign a list object to it, _not_ when you add items to that list. I'm not really sure what you mean by `Properties -> Items -> [(Collection) ...]` though.

Comment: @TaW I can do that but it is not going into my list anyway

Comment: Can you describe more what this means:  `Properties -> Items -> [(Collection) ...]` ?

Comment: I don't understand. As it is all Buttons would sit on top of each other..

Comment: In winform normally on the bottom right that is this properties menu where you can change the backcolor, name, forecolor and etc

Comment: @TaW  My issue is that the buttons should at least show but it is currently not showing itself

Comment: @albusSimba Yes (it's called the Properties window), but it does _not_ have an `Items` element by default, unless the control has a property called `Items`. Your question is really not that clear. Please [edit] the question and provide a [repro] and try to explain your end goal because this might not be the best way. For example, you might consider using a `FlowLayoutPanel` control instead of your custom panel.

Comment: Yes I am trying to create a custom property that is called `Buttons`

Comment: Your code is not working as expected because `List<>` is a collection per se, while `Panel.Controls` is a totally different collection!! You should need to synchronize them in both directions every time one of them is modified, but `List<>` does not allow such kind of behavior. Maybe changing `List<Button>` to `Button[]` can resolve or help. You should re-think the goals of such approach: do you need a collection of `Button`-only controls because you want to filter out any other kind of `Control`, or... you only want `Button` controls to be added to the panel?

Comment: Rule no 1: Use the debugger!! If you do you will at once see whether the setter code is run when expected. - Also: Do note  41686d6564 1st comment !!!

Comment: @TaW note that the issue is probably occurring in the Properties window of a designer, that you **can not** debug unless running a second instance of the development environment (Visual Studio ?) and attach its debugger to the instance where the designer is running. An alternative to a real debugger could be logging/displaying messages (MessageBox.Show, Console.WriteLine or custom alternative) by adding explicit instructions throughout the code to debug.

Comment: @Rubidium37 I tried to use an array instead of a list i think the main issues here is that it is not adding to the list/array because there is no add function being auto generated. Yes i kinda watered down the question because i need to filter out the other controls.

Comment: @albusSimba You can try to decorate the `Buttons` property with `[Editor(typeof(ArrayEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]`.. `ArrayEditor` is a system-provided class to help editing arrays at design time... You can even derive a custom class from it and in case make to instantiate a custom `CollectionForm`. Anyway, **if filtering is your will, and preserving other controls is a requirement**, then the `get` accessor should build the array at each request and the `buttons` field is useless. Moreover, `Controls.Clear` inside `set` would be dangerous because non-`Button` controls would be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a `CustomPanel` class has been added as a custom control, and its base class changed to `Panel`, you can try the following code.

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Design;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TEST
{
    public partial class CustomPanel : Panel
    {
        public CustomPanel()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        [Editor(typeof(ArrayEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
        public Button[] Buttons
        {
            get { return this.Controls.OfType<Button>().ToArray(); }
            set
            {
                SuspendLayout();
                try
                {
                    this.Controls.Clear();

                    foreach (var button in value)
                    {
                        button.Size = new Size(200, 30);
                        this.Controls.Add(button);
                    }
                }
                finally { ResumeLayout(); }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure the project has a reference to `System.Design.dll`, for `ArrayEditor` to be recognized.

Keep in mind that:

- Every `Button` control added by the designer through the `Buttons` property will be serialized like it was added in the usual design way.
- Adding other (non-`Button`) controls is still possibile in the usual design way, or programmatically.
- `this.Controls.Clear` will remove any control, even the ones added without using `Buttons`; you can delete this instruction if you want to preserve them, but you will need a way to recognize the previously existing buttons and replace or keep them as needed.
- All properties of any `Button` object can be edited inside the `ArrayEditor` form.
- You need to handle positioning of the `Button` controls (both newly added and existing ones) in order to avoid overlapping.

I suggest to use a child `FlowLayoutPanel` for automatic positioning of the buttons and to prevent anyone to mess directly with the collection of buttons. With this approach, `this.Controls` will become `flowLayoutPanel1.Controls` (or similar).
Otherwise, you should override `OnControlAdded` and `OnControlRemoved` to be notified when any control is added or removed.